# Forcefully run program in Vista RFM (Reduced Functionality Mode)

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox

The idea is to use Vista RFM as a freeware version of Windows to allow Mac users running a Windows-based application via VirtualBox. 
Is there a way to make that possible (starting the program automatically in RFM)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add it as a service (using [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/)) to automatically start it as a service, or add it to the startup entries in the registry, to start it as soon as you log in. There is a free older version of FireDaemon available (though it can only run one service) [FireDaemon Lite](http://www.unrealadmin.org/forums/attachment.php?s=7a329d69a0ec33f96522a5bd8972bb1b&attachmentid=333&d=1087301481).